# I want to search "1947 (AS) ARD 22" this string in MongoDb with regex

Tags: mongodb

The regex method ignores the brackets to i cant serch this string from regex in mongodb

i want record which contain this string
this query does not work:

db.collection.findOne({ctext:{$regex : "1947 (AS) ARD 22"}});

Comment: Because it contains parenthesis it does not show proper result

Comment: Test your regex, escape parenthesis like this -  https://regexr.com/5p2rr